# Is there a way to see RBAC events for GKE clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, rbac, kubernetes-rbac

I have a GKE cluster that uses a mix of Cloud IAM and cluster RBAC rules for resource access. For granularity, we use RBAC bindings for certain resources on the cluster, but I'm unable to find a place where those events are logged.

How do I see the logs for when cluster RBAC denies a user the permissions to do something? I can only see IAM related logs in Cloud Logging's audit logs. I'd like to know when the cluster itself denies access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the Kube API logs

```
kubectl proxy &
curl -s http://localhost:8001/logs/kube-apiserver.log
```

While GKE logs : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/audit-logging#viewing_logs

Answer (score 1):

You can find the GCP events in the GKE audit logs as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/audit-logging).

The RBAC related events can be obtained from the kubeapi server as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/)